# Group sum of a column and insert

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, group-by

I have a unique situation here. I am sorry of the question is too naive or unclear.

I have a table ( called Table1 ) that looks like this:

```
Student First Name | Last name  |  ID     | Test Name   | Result

Anthony            | Davis      | 12353   | abc_1_1    | Pass
Chris              | Tucker     | 23412   | abc_1_3    | Fail
Anthony            | Davis      | 12355   | abc_2_4    | Fail
Anthony            | Davis      | 12356   | abc_2_1    | Pass
Anthony            | Davis      | 12635   | abc_1-5    | Fail
Anthony            | Davis      | 12375   | abc_2_3    | Pass
Anthony            | Davis      | 12935   | abc_1_8    | Fail
Chris              | Tucker     | 23341   | abc_1_2    | Pass
Chris              | Tucker     | 23541   | abc_2_3    | Pass
Chris              | Tucker     | 23431   | abc_1_4    | Fail
Chris              | Tucker     | 21341   | abc_2_1    | Pass
Chris              | Tucker     | 32341   | abc_1_6    | Fail
David              | Steel      | 34352   | abc_2_3    | Fail
David              | Steel      | 34352   | abc_1_2    | Pass
David              | Steel      | 34352   | abc_2_4    | Fail
David              | Steel      | 34352   | abc_1_1    | Pass
David              | Steel      | 34352   | abc_1_7    | Fail
```

The table (table2) what I am trying to achieve is like :

```
Name         | Test Type | Pass | Fail

AnthonyDavis | Type_1    | 1    | 2
AnthonyDavis | Type_2    | 2    | 1
ChrisTucker  | Type_1    | 1    | 2
ChrisTucker  | Type_1    | 1    | 2
DavidSteel   | Type_1    | 2    | 1
DavidSteel   | Type_1    | 0    | 1
```

Is it possible to achieve this is SQL?
The `primary key for Table2 is (Name,Test Type)`
Or is it easier to have a temporary table collect the data needed and then transfer that to Table2?

Comment: How do you get `Test Type`?

Comment: That was based on what numbers in the last part of the test name

ie : abc_1_1 belongs to type 1
if there is a test named abc_45_2 it would be type 45

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the `TestType` values are based on the first five characters of the `TestName`, then you should be able to use something similar to this to SELECT the data:

```
-- insert into Table2 (name, TestType, Pass, Fail)
select concat(StudentFirstName, Lastname) name,
  case left(TestName, 5)
      when 'abc_1' then 'Type_1'
      when 'abc_2' then 'Type_2'
    end testtype,
  sum(case when result = 'Pass' then 1 else 0 end) Pass,
  sum(case when result = 'Fail' then 1 else 0 end) Fail
from Table1
group by concat(StudentFirstName, Lastname), 
  case left(TestName, 5)
      when 'abc_1' then 'Type_1'
      when 'abc_2' then 'Type_2'
    end;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb39a/1). Once you have the data in the format that you want, then you can easily insert it into `Table2`.

If my assumption about how you get the `TestType` is not correct, then please provide the details on how you determine this.

Note, MySQL allows the alias from the SELECT to be used in the GROUP BY:

```
-- insert into Table2 (name, TestType, Pass, Fail)
select concat(StudentFirstName, Lastname) name,
  case left(TestName, 5)
      when 'abc_1' then 'Type_1'
      when 'abc_2' then 'Type_2'
    end testtype,
  sum(case when result = 'Pass' then 1 else 0 end) Pass,
  sum(case when result = 'Fail' then 1 else 0 end) Fail
from Table1
group by name, testtype;
```

Comment: For that matter, MySQL also allows `Pass` and `Fail` to be defined as `SUM(result='Pass')` and `SUM(result='Fail')` respectively.  :)

Comment: Can you explain this statement "case left (testname,5)"  ?

Comment: @KumaranSenapathy You did not specify how you determine the test type, by looking at the data it appears that there were two tests starting with `abc_1` and `abc_2`. I assumed that this is how you determine the different types.  As a result, I am selecting the left, 5 characters from the testName column.  This is then used to get the text types.

Comment: Also.. when you use when abc_1 then type 1,
wont it get abc_10_2 into type 1 rather than type 10?

Comment: @KumaranSenapathy As I said, you need to explain how you determine the test types. I made an assumption based on the limited info you provided. You only showed two versions, If you have more than you will need to alter the code accordingly.

Comment: Is it possible to do a "like" when determining the types?
eg : "like %_1_% then type 1"
,"like %_10_% then type 10"
etc?

Comment: Thank you. Please correct me if I am wrong:
Case left(testname,5)
when like %_1_% then type 1
When like %_10_% then type 10

Comment: Thanks again @bluefeet . Appreciate your help.